# Substitute vertical for horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, scroll

I'm trying to put a method in my website where if a user uses the scroll on their mouse, instead of it scrolling up and down it changes the input to scrolling left and right. I've added something called mousewheel.js to my project and I reference jquery in the header, and I'm running some code that I found on a thread on this site, but I can't get it to work, could anyone please point out what's wrong with my code.

HTML:

```
  <head>
    <title> Calendar </title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

  </head>

<body>

<script>$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
if($(this).scrollLeft()>=0 && $(this).scrollLeft()<=$('body').width())
var k =  $(this).scrollLeft()-delta*50;
$(this).scrollLeft(k)
});</script>
```

Thanks for all help and advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you're open to simple Javascript (no plugins), look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23967214/5976846) I found to a similar (same?) question.

```
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();
```

I've tested it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/96e1bhw7/) using Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you code is a little different than the `mousewheel` example I see that works, try this:

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

> Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/