# scroll bar in jquery (need to place a scroll bar on the bottom of the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want to get the same result like this horizontal scroll bar on this page: https://www.claytonbozard.com/#5

I need to create a scrollbar that will look like the default bottom scroll bar and always will be placed at the bottom of the page and will scroll only a specific section. (not all the page, only a specific section)
Can anyone assist me with that?

I have this code but the scroll bar doesn't place on the bottom of the page:

```css
.wrapper {
  /* background: #EFEFEF; */
  /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999; */
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  /* margin-bottom: 20px !important; */
  width: 100%;
  /* padding-top: 5px; */
}

.scrolls {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* height: 300px; */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.scrolls img {
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: -5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrolls">
    <img src="images/01.jpg" />
    <img src="images/04.jpg" />
    <img src="images/07.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Mousewheel Scroll Horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952491/jquery-mousewheel-scroll-horizontally)

Comment: where is your code that shows what you've tried already?  where specifically are you getting stuck?

Comment: @DanO added code